# Scraping URLS of several pages from one website

Tags: r, url, web-scraping

I'm pretty sure.. somewhere in the community this question has been already answered. But for some reasons, I cannot find the answer I wish for.
I started text mining and webscraping in R just recently.
And I have a hard time understanding html codes (haven't work with html before either) and I can scrape all the info I want from one website/page.
But I wished I could that for all the "next page" from this website.
I programmed an alternative but it is not very convenient to use.

```
# I know the website has 9902 items and 50 items per page:
i <- 1
info <- c()
while (i < 9902) { 
  print(i)
  i = i+50 
  info <- c(info,i)
}

URL_OG <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&year=2020-01-01,2020-12-31&start="
URL_OG_end <- "&ref_=adv_nxt"

create_URL <- function(x) {
paste0(URL_OG,x,URL_OG_end)
}
URLS <- unlist(lapply(info,create_URL))
# Now I have a list of URLS. But this is a stupid solution...
```

Could I use html_nodes(text,css='.next-page') or something ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not stupid at all, if it works for you (as in it gets you the data you need) then that is all you need. It is even common to create the list of needed urls and then parsing them for the data.

That said you can, as you mentioned, also use `html_nodes` and `html_node`, if you know what you're looking for, here is one way:

```r
library(rvest)
base_url = "https://www.imdb.com"

## first page
page_url <- "/search/title/?title_type=feature&year=2020-01-01,2020-12-31"
# read page
page <- read_html(paste0(base_url, page_url))
# get movie titles
movie_titles <- page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header") %>% html_node("a") %>% html_text()
print(length(movie_titles))
# get the node for the next page
next_node <- page %>% html_node(".next-page")

## while there's a next page repeate the above steps
while (!is.na(next_node)) {
  # get next page url
  page_url <- next_node %>% html_attr("href")
  # read page
  page <- read_html(paste0(base_url, page_url))
  # get movie titles
  movie_titles <- page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header") %>% html_node("a") %>% html_text()
  print(length(movie_titles))
  # get the node for the next page
  next_node <- page %>% html_node(".next-page")
  # print(next_node)
}
```

Comment: But by this, I cannot create a list of all URLs right?

Comment: in this case you don't need to. But of course if you need the urls for something else you can always save the urls before reading the page, e.g., `urls <- c(urls, paste0(base_url, page_url))`